# How to use DateFormatter

Tags: ios

```
let formatter: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yy.MM.dd"
    return formatter
}()
```

I'm trying to convert dates using this variable.

```
print(formatter.date(from: "23.11.30"))
```

Result

```
Optional(2023-11-29 15:00:00 +0000)
```

I thought it was the 30th, but it said 29th.

I am curious as to why this output is not coming out correctly.

Do I need to make other settings?
I wonder what I'm missing.

I guess TimeZone setting.

I am curious as to why dates are not converted properly by default.

Comment: Your code is fine. The output is correct. Midnight on November 30, 2023 in your timezone is 3pm on November 29, 2023 UTC. This assumes you live in the UTC+9 timezone.

Comment: Try passing the date value back through the formatter - it's possible you have a timezone issue (as `Date` is using UTC)

Comment: Thank you everyone.
based on your opinions, we can now reconsider.

I was able to resolve the issue by setting the 'TimeZone' to 'GMT'.